# How can I group rows into columns with multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping, pivot-table

How can I group an unknown number of rows into a single row, where the set columns determine the grouping?

I want to shift

```
Group1   Group2   Group3    Val1   Val2   Val3
===============================================
John      Smith     25      1      0      0
John      Smith     25      0      6      0
John      Smith     25      0      0      8
Chris     Green     30      0      3      0
Chris     Green     30      5      0      0
```

into

```
Group1   Group2   Group3    Val1   Val2   Val3
===============================================
John      Smith     25      1      6      8
Chris     Green     30      5      3      0
```

Comment: GROUP BY Group1   Group2   Group3, SUM on val1 - val3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table (group1 varchar(10),group2 varchar(20),group3 int,val1 int,val2 int,val3 int)

insert into @t (group1,group2,group3,val1,val2,val3)values ('John','Smith',25,1,0,0),
('John','Smith',25,1,6,0),
('John','Smith',25,1,0,8),
('Chris','Green',30,1,0,0),
('Chris','Green',30,1,3,0),
('Chris','Green',30,5,0,0)

select distinct group1,group2,group3,MAX(val1),MAX(val2),MAX(val3) from @t
group by group1,group2,group3 
ORDER BY group1 desc,group2 desc
```

Comment: why you use `distinct` with `group by`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Group1, Group2, Group3, SUM(val1), SUM(val2), SUM(val3)
from tablename
GROUP BY Group1, Group2, Group3
```

Comment: So basic SQL, so I didn't even think of it. (Also, I have to work too.)

Comment: Hey, I took time to edit the question, to wrote a comment, and when no one else answered I even wrote an answer. I don't think thats low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `group by` clause with the `sum` aggregate function, but for this to work, you MUST ensure that the data type of the `val` columns is of a numeric data type (`int`, `decimal`, `smallint`, etc.)
Also, any `null` values will be ignored by the `sum` function

```
select Group1, Group2, Group3, sum(val1), sum(val2), sum(val3)
from <table_name>
group by Group1, Group2, Group3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query itself has your answer. you want to group your gropunames and perform SUm on other columns. all you need to do a simple query where

```
select sum(Val1 ),sum( Val2), sum(  Val3) from table 
group by Group1 ,  Group2,   Group3
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp